# Passing variable argument to another function

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I need to pass variable argument to another function. The problem is that this argument is an function and i have no idea how to determine the type of funtion. For example i have function: char(*)char(c), how to read it by va_arg?

```
void process(const char* typ ...)
{
    char c;
    va_list ap;
    
    va_start(ap, typ);

    while (*typ != 0)
    {
        switch (*typ)
        {
            case'p':
                //change(va_arg(ap, char*), va_arg(ap, char(*)char(c)));
            case 'f':
                //filterr(va_arg(ap, char*), va_arg(ap, bool(*)char));
            case 's':
                char* a = va_arg(ap, char*);
                char* b = va_arg(ap, char*);
                encrypt(a, b);
                break;
        }
    }
}

char changeToUppear(char c) {
    return (c >= 'a' and c <= 'z') ? c - 32 : c;
}
bool leaveLowercase(char c) {
    return (c < 'a' or c>'z');
}
```

Comment: Some actual code would help. Have you ever used varargs before? Do you have a good reference on how they work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Comment: I have never used them before. I read quite alot and I had a lesson about them.

Comment: You can use a va_list as an argument to a function. Take a look at `vprintf()` and its siblings, for example.

Comment: Why do you want to use varargs here? What's the advantage of the monolithic whopper `process("pfs",s1,changeToUppear,s2,leaveLowercase,s3,"TAJNE");` over the more usual `map(s1, toUpper); filter(s2, isLower); encrypt(s3, "TAJNE");`, which gives you the benefit of type safety?`

Comment: Don't try to pass the functions as arguments.  Just use the value of `*typ` to decide which function to call.  That is, `switch(*typ){ ...; char *a = va_arg(ap, char *); leaveLowercase(*a);...}`

Comment: Do not call `va_arg` twice in function argument list. You never know witch one be first. Also `va_arg(ap, char(*)char(c))` -> `va_arg(ap, char(*)char)`

Comment: Because this is just an open test, in other tests i dont know how many arguments tere will be.

Comment: and also order of arguments is known before, for ecample for p first argument is a char array, second a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> char(*)char(c), how to read it by va_arg?

Just take it, like any other type. The function type is `char (*)(char)`. After correcting many typos in your code, the following compiles:

```
#include <iso646.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
void change(char (*func)(char), char *pnt);
char filterr(bool (*func)(char), char *pnt);
void encrypt(char *, char*);

void process(const char* typ, ...) {
//                          ^ !!
    char c;
    va_list ap;   
    va_start(ap, typ);
    while (*typ != 0) {
        switch (*typ) {
            case'p': {
                char *pnt = va_arg(ap, char*);
                char (*func)(char) = va_arg(ap, char (*)(char));
                change(pnt, func);
            }
                break;
            case 'f': {
                char *pnt = va_arg(ap, char*);
                bool (*func)(char) = va_arg(ap, bool (*)(char));
                filterr(pnt, func);
            }
                break;
            case 's': {
                char* a = va_arg(ap, char*); // it's not possible to declare variable after case!
                char* b = va_arg(ap, char*);
                encrypt(a, b);
            }
                break;
        }
    }
    va_end(ap); // remember about va_end!
}

char changeToUppear(char c) {
    // prefer toupper from ctype.h
    return (c >= 'a' and c <= 'z') ? c - 32 : c;
}
bool leaveLowercase(char c) {
    // prefer islower() != 0 from ctype.h
    return (c < 'a' or c>'z');
}

int main() 
{
    char s1[] = "Ala ma kota.";
    char s2[] = "Kot ma Ale!";
    char s3[] = "to jest bardzo tajny tekst";
    process("pfs",s1,changeToUppear,s2,leaveLowercase,s3,"TAJNE");
}
```